Why detach probs in symmetric_kl function (deberta shift)
In the official implementation of sift by Microsoft/Deberta here, they implemented symmetric_kl function as:
def symmetric_kl(logits, target):
  logit_stu = logits.view(-1, logits.size(-1)).float()
  logit_tea = target.view(-1, target.size(-1)).float()
  logprob_stu = F.log_softmax(logit_stu, -1)
  logprob_tea = F.log_softmax(logit_tea, -1)
  prob_tea = logprob_tea.exp().detach()
  prob_stu = logprob_stu.exp().detach()
  floss = ((prob_tea*(-logprob_stu)).sum(-1))    # Cross Entropy
  bloss = ((prob_stu*(-logprob_tea)).sum(-1))    # Cross Entropy
  loss = floss + bloss
  return loss

My question is why do you need to detach() when computing prob_tea and prob_stu.
I checked and found that its presence affects the gradients computed.
